# How to bind TextBoxes to individual elements in a Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, observablecollection

I have a class with an ObservableCollection called List and I am trying to bind to textboxes individually. I have been trying:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source=List[0], Path=Value}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source=List[1], Path=Value}"/>
```

The StringObject class is just:

```
class StringObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: I think we're going to need a lot more info. WPF or Silverlight? What is "List" in the context of the XAML you've posted? Is it a property on the DataContext of the window?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this is a WPF application and 'List' is declared in the code behind the window as shown by Nathan below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If this is for a WPF app.**

Given this code behind:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ListCon();
        }
    }

    public class ListCon
    {
        public List<StringObject> List
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new List<StringObject>();
                list.Add(new StringObject() { Value = "Hello World" });
                return list;
            }
        }
    }

    public class StringObject
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

The binding would look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding List[0].Value}" />
```